# Is this possible to make a hybrid app compatible with different ARM architectures?

Tags: android, arm

I want my hybrid app to work with different ARM version (ARMv7, ARMv6 and ARMv5). Is this even possible?

Comment: Were there ever any ARMv5 Android devices? Even the G1 was using ARMv6. If there were any I'd be surprised if any of them still are in use. Anyway, you can compile for the oldest architecture you want to support and that code will run on newer architectures as well.

Comment: Do you mean to say a fat binary which contains libraries for all supported architectures ?

Comment: Generally user code (most Linux drivers even) will be backwards compatible, but in-efficient if you target an older ARM.  So it is automatically compatible.  However, if you want to take advantage of ARMv7 features, then you can ID the CPU and use function pointer to call CPU intensive routines appropriate for the CPU type.  A 'fat' binary would only be needed if you had CPUs like an ARM and x86.  (PowerPC and x86 in apple case).  You may have difficulty in using ARMv7 op-codes in a binary that reports ARMv6 compatibility.

Comment: Ok, so if my app will be set to devices with ARMv6 architecture, will also work on ARMv7 architecture, right? And if I set my app to devices with ARMv7 architecture, it won't work on ARMv6 architecture? And if I already have ARMv7 app, how to compile it to the ARMv6 version?